# Why my javascript dispatchEvent is not working

Tags: javascript, dispatchevent

below is my javascript code. previousPage and NextPage are working properly with HTML button elements.
But I am not sure why addEventListener('wheel') is not working. So I inserted some console.log, then I realize var delta is corret. But, I guess there is a problem 'if (delta ~ ~' area...

```
const pageList = document.querySelectorAll('.verticalPaging');
const previousPage = document.querySelector('#previousScroller');
const nextPage = document.querySelector('#nextScroller');
const idlePeriod = 100;
const animationDuration = 1000;
let lastAnimation = 0;
let pageIndex = 0;

previousPage.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    if (pageIndex < 1) return;
    pageIndex--;
    pageList.forEach((section, i) => {
        if (i === pageIndex) {
            section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        }
    });
});

nextPage.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (pageIndex > 4) return;
    pageIndex++;
    pageList.forEach((section, i) => {
        if (i === pageIndex) {
            section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        }
    })
});




document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    var delta = event.wheelDelta;
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
    if(timeNow - lastAnimation < idlePeriod + animationDuration) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if (delta < 0) {
        var event = new Event('click');
        nextPage.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        var event = new Event('click');
        previousPage.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    lastAnimation = timeNow;
},{passive: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

The wheel event doesn't have a `wheelDelta` property, but it has `deltaY` which I guess you are actually after.

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {

    const timeNow = new Date().getTime();

    // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
    if(timeNow - lastAnimation < idlePeriod + animationDuration) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    const clickEvent = new Event('click')

    if (event.deltaY < 0) {

        nextPage.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    } else {

        previousPage.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }

    lastAnimation = timeNow;
},{passive: false});
```

I took the liberty to get rid of var